# Tab bar in Xcode 4.3 visible on all screens / Storryboard

Tags: xcode

I am using Xcode 4.3. I have a tab bar controller with 3 tab bar items, each of these link to separate view controllers. On one of the view controllers I have a custom button that links to another view controller. I can link this button to open the new view controller (through storyboards) however the tab bar (from my previous screen) is not present. How can I keep the tab bar for all items that open when I add new view controllers? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly sure you can't do that. If there is a way I would love to know.

However in the past I've compensated for this problem by creating buttons to simulate a tab bar view and load in controllers that way. Its not ideal but the best solution I've come up with for this situation.